# OpenCV Training Custom Haar Cascade

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am trying to train a haar cascade on my face. I have everything setup including the positive, negetive, the vec file, etc. but when I run the opencv_traincascade, it gave me a `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` error. Then I added this line to my arguments `-nonsym -mem 512` and it gave me this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'`.

Here is the command I am running:

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt\
>    -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000\
>    -numNeg 600 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024\
>    -precalcIdxBufSize 1024\
>    -nonsym\
>    -mem 512\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get rid of the `-nonsym -mem 512` and instead put `-mode ALL`. So new the command looks like this:

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt\
>    -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000\
>    -numNeg 600 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024\
>    -precalcIdxBufSize 1024\
>    -mode ALL
```

The `-nonsym -mem512` commands don't actually exist.